# Migrating openID2.0 to Google+ with python-social-auth (Mapping openid id to gplus id)

Tags: django, migration, google-plus, python-social-auth, openid2

We were previously using openID 2.0, and have a database full of users and their associated openids. In light of the deprecation of this protocol we decided to go with Google+ signins instead.

`python-social-auth` made this relatively straightforward in the Django project, but now I'm unsure of how to map our existing user's openid to the newer Google sub id.

I added

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_AUTH_EXTRA_ARGUMENTS = {'openid.realm': 'http://www.example.com'}
```

to the settings.py, and I can see `python-social-auth` has took note and passes `?openid.realm=http://www.example.com` in the GET string along with scopes etc, as it should. However Google does not seem to respond with an OpenID id. I only get the `id_token` (along with `access_token`, `bearer` etc).

How do I get Google to respond with the actual openid for the user?

(the only docs from Google I can find on OpenID2.0 to Google+ migration, seem more geared toward their javascript signin buttong, e.g. https://developers.google.com/+/api/auth-migration#oid2)

**EDIT:** Maybe the id is encoded somehow in the `id_token`, if so, how do I decode?